# Прилагательное «двоякий» — особенное?

Tags: прилагательные

Еремей Парнов. Третий глаз Шивы:

> — Разве цари — не люди?
> — Ты проповедуешь опасные мысли.
> — Разве боги — не цари?
> — Твоя истина **двояка**.
> — Всякая истина **двояка**, шахиншах. Разве свет и мрак могут существовать друг без друга? Благая Мысль, Благое Слово, Благое Дело — вот истина истин, великое триединство Мазды.

Всем известна вот такая формулировка:
относительные прилагательные — это слова, которые обозначают постоянный признак через отношение к другому предмету (*стеклянная чашка — чашка из стекла, осенний день — день осени*) и **не имеют краткой формы** и степеней сравнения.

В [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) у прилагательного краткие формы отсутствуют, а в [БТС](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) — имеются.
*Двоякий* (и *троякий*, конечно же) — это какое-то особенное прилагательное? Может, и не относительное вовсе?
Есть ли еще такие — нестандартные?

Comment: Римма! Жду ответа на свой комментарий вчерашний в теме, где ты ответила на мой вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, оно все-таки не относительное, а качественное прилагательные.
В викисловаре краткие формы присутствуют: [ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/двояк#Русский](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BA#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Mark, Ваша ссылка ведёт на школьную оценку 2 (двояк).

Comment: Нет, см. первое значение: "краткая форма мужского рода прилагательного двоякий".

Comment: Да, спасибо, не заметил из-за большей статьи второго значения. Сделайте, пожалуйста, ссылку кликабельной.

Comment: @MarkKahn Приветствую Вас на сайте! Если Вы нажмете на первый "двояк", то и выйдете на прилагательное "двоякий" в ВС (моя ссылка). Оно указано как относительное, и кратких форм нет, только падежные.

Comment: Ок, добавил и в викисловарь.

Comment: Ух ты! Но все равно считаете, что оно качественное?

Comment: Не 100%, но именно ваш аргумент про краткую форму довольно убедителен.